# How to create a bootable volume from image for bluemix's VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I tried to create a bootable volume from image for bluemix's VM in london area.
i created a bootable volume first,

```
cinder create --image-id image's id --display_name=myinstance1 50
```

then i type

```
openstack volume show volume's id
```

it show bootable state is false and status is error. what is wrong with me? and how to create a bootable volume from image? thanks